# Latex Installation with TeX Collection 2020 DVD

Tags: latex, texlive

Am running Ubuntu 20.04. Yesterday I installed LaTeX using DVD TexCollection 2020. everything went find. set the PATH.rebooted.

tried running xelatex on my file: xelatex testfile.tex

did not work. It returned Command 'xelatex' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install texlive-xetex

What details would one need to know the problem?

Comment: Have you installed `texlive-xetex` like the error message suggested?

Comment: On another note, it would have been nice of you to accept (and upvote) the answer you got for the other question. It a great answer and took a lot of effort. Saying "WOW", DANKE" in comments is unneeded and even frown upon, accepting and upvoting answers (and questions) is how the site works so, please, act accordingly.

Comment: not yet. Initially I had installed the DVD fully (all the files). and my command worked. a bit later I edited my file and ran xelatex again. It failed. I uninstalled texlive fully using 

rm -rf /usr/local/texlive/2020
rm -rf ~/.texlive2020

reinstalled everything.  

but is not working. I cannot even use the command "latex".

Answer (score 2):

You need to install `texlive-xetex` package which provide `xelatex` command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
sudo apt install texlive-xetex
```

To install the full version of latex:

```
sudo apt install texlive-full
```

Comment: Thank you. If I understand you correctly, then the installation from the DVD is not enough. Please correct me, if I am wrong. I have never experienced this problem before. Been using LaTeX since 1999. I have always installed using the DVD (earlier CD)

Comment: @Srinath I don't know the content of the DVD. But the program is packaged under Ubutnu, it will be more easy to install it through `apt`.

Comment: the TeX Collection 2020 is a collection of a large number of  files. It includes ProTeXt, TeXLive, MacTeX and a collection from CTAN. TUG members get the DVD. I used to install my LaTeX system using these DVDs.  Interestingly, it works on my second laptop running Ubuntu 18.04.  Could be a system problem

Thank you. I am right now installing using apt. Doing a full installation. Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

As for many programs, there are two ways to install :

1. Ubuntu package system `apt install`.
2. Directly TeXLive.

`apt` will install in `/usr/bin`.
TeXLive 2020 will install in `/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin`.

Both should be able to configure command path correctly.  You can also use `kapthsea` and `texdoc` to locate TeX files (but you may have to locate them first in TeX tree).

I use TeXLive because I have used it even before Ubuntu.  As you have the TeXLive DVD, just use it, but look for help on TeX groups, not Askubuntu.  My experience is that the TeXLive installer works very well and using it is very instructive if you have some time to spend.

TeXLive may miss some peculiarities of Ubuntu.  A typical problem is the access to system fonts.  `apt` will be slightly out of date or may be less complete, depending on editing choices.

You can have both (although it is a waste of space) and you can choose which one runs by default in $PATH.

TeXLive is available on DVD and online.  DVD may be more or less as (slightly) outdated as Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you. All these years I used the TexLive on DVD (initially  on CD) , on my Ubuntu laptop. It always worked. This time it worked and all of a sudden it stopped working and I could not find out why. Tried twice. Then I uninstalled it completely and used apt and now it is working. Since I don't use any office software, I need LaTeX for documents. However, I am not technically fit but I learn fast. I shall search for kpathsea and texdoc. Really need to master this platform.